# Why unsafe context is not required to call C functions from C# program?

Tags: c#, clr, unsafe

I recently started working on C# programming(I worked only on C before). I came to know that we need to use unsafe context to use pointers in C# program as [Microsoft docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/index).

One of the advantages of not using pointers are

> Using unsafe code introduces security and stability risks.

But we don't need to use unsafe context to call functions in C which may contains poorly written code or security vulnerabilities. [Common Language Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/clr) Can't detect problems in these C functions.

**These are my questions**

1. Why it is not required to use unsafe context to execute functions written in C even though CLR can't detect problems in these code?
2. What may be the advantage of not using the unsafe context for calling functions written in C?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18987033/why-does-c-sharp-interop-not-require-unsafe-compiler-option), but since that question does not have an answer, I will not close this one. Instead, I've closed the other question as a duplicate of this one (since this one DOES have an answer).

Comment: The C# language can only apply `unsafe` to C# declarations.  [DllImport] is just an attribute, the language doesn't know anything about it.  The only C#-specific part of it is the `extern` keyword, the vast majority of them are implemented in the CLR and are not unsafe.  Another good example are unions declared with [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicity].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why it is not required to use unsafe context to execute functions written in C even though CLR can't detect problems in these code?

Unsafe mode isn't about the method being called that is unsafe, C# code can be equally unsafe. Unsafe mode is about the memory management which is bypassed. If you allocate variables though the CLR (so managed), which are passed to C++ libraries, like the Win32 libraries, the CLR can still manage the memory segments used, since they are still CLR variables.

> What may be the advantage of not using the unsafe context for calling functions written in C?

If you don't need unsafe memory allocation, there is no point in using an `unsafe` context.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I have one doubt. What about the dynamic memory allocations done in the C functions which is executes through C# program? If these memory are not getting freed then wont it be keep allocated to the C# program and leads to memory leak?

Comment: Well, yes, but that is out of control of the CLR.

Comment: What I meant is, If CLR don't have any control over these allocations, Then calling these C functions should be under unsafe context?

Comment: No. The `unsafe` context is only for unsafe allocations though CLR managed code. Not though external code.